# Insert new Documents or modify an array field of existing document

Tags: mongodb, mono, pymongo

Apologies if this is a re-post, but I wasn't able to quite get the query I want from the mongodb documentation examples.

Here's my issue. I am unable execute in a single query to either update an array_field of an existing document or add a new document and initialize the array_field with an initial value.

I can use findOne() with some conditional logic, and probably solve this, but I would think mongodb has an implementation of this use case

Here's the code so far:

```
#data_json = JSON document to be added to collection

collection.update_one({"json_id":data_json["json_id"], "_dashbd_id_":dashboard_id},{{"$addToSet": {"array_field":keyword}},{"$setOnInsert":data_json}}, upsert=True)
```

I'm querying by the json_id, and _dashbd_id_ from my collection. If it exists, then I intend to add the "keyword" to the array_field. If it doesn't exist, create a new document as data_json which include array_field = [keyword]

Any hints and suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think that you need `$setOnInsert` ? You query is unclear. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: setOnInsert to add the document to the collection if it doesn't exist (aka, no matches are found with th given "json_id" and "_dashbd_id_" )

Answer (score 5):

If I understood you correctly you want to update values in Database only if they do not exist as well as create new documents with arrays in them. Okay there is a way in mongodb which I will mention in this reply. I think you should know few commands first that will help you achieve similar result (again there is a simple way just read on)

Let me start with the first part:

to **update** an element in an array you use dot notation to the index example:

```
db.collection_name.update({"_id": id}, {'$set': {"array_name.indexNumber": value}})
```

say we have the following document in collection name *cars*

```
db.cars.findOne():
{
 _id: 1
 name: EvolutionX
 brand: Mitsubish
 year: 2012
 mods: [ turbo, headlights ] 
}
```

Say in the above example we want to update *headlights* with *rearlights* we do the following (using mongoshell you can drop quotes in key names, **Not** when using the array index though):

```
db.cars.update({id:1}, {$set:{"mods.1":"rearlights"}})
```

*1* is the index to headlights.

**Note** and **be careful** here that if you did not use index inside of an array like

```
db.cars.update({id:1}, {$set:{"mods":"rearlights"}})
```

this will overwrite the existing document *_id:1* and it will lose all other attributes or fields inside the document so it will result in the follow:

```
db.cars.findOne():
{
 _id: 1
 mods: [ rearlights ] 
}
```

Now, say we want to add an element *tires* to *mods* array you can use **$push** as:

```
db.collection_name.update({"_id": id}, {'$push': {"array_name": value}})
```

so it will be

```
db.cars.update({"_id":1}, {"$push":{"mods":"tires"}})
```

now say instead of updating *mods* array you want to remove "*headlights*". In this case you use **$pop**

```
db.cars.update({"_id":1}, {"$pop":{"mods":"headlights"}})
```

Now with that in mind. **The easy way**: in mongodb to add to array only if element does not exist you can use **$addToSet**. I love this operator because it will only add to array if the element does not exist. Here is how to use it:

```
db.cars.update({"_id":1}, {"$addToSet":{"mods":"headlights"}})
```

Now if *headlights* is in the array it will not be added, else it will be added to the end of array.

Okay that is the first part of the question. The second part which is initializing a document with an array. Okay there are two thoughts here: the first is you do not have to. using the **addToSet** you can create the array if it does not exist as (assuming *_id 2* exist but **without** *mods* array):

```
db.cars.update({"_id":2}, {"$addToSet":{"mods":"bonnet"}})
```

This will create the array if document **_id:2 exist**. Assuming *_id:3* does not exist you will have plug in a third attribute called **upsert**

```
db.cars.update({"_id":3}, {"$addToSet":{"mods":"headlights"}}, {upsert:true})
```

this will create a third document with array *mods* with *headlights* inside of it and *_id:3*. Note though **no other** attributes will be added only the *_id* and *mods* array

the second thought is when you insert a new document you insert it with empty *mods*  array as *mod:[]*
I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks ibininja for that informative post! I think I was being greedy and wanted to do the action in one mongo query as opposed to two. I ended up doing an if/else statement, and figuring out my need. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

suppose your data_json ,dashboard_id and  keyword contain following detail.

```
   dashboard_id = ObjectId("5423200e6694ce357ad2a1ac")
   keyword = "testingKeyword"
   data_json = 
   {  
           "json_id":ObjectId("5423200e6694ce357ad2a1ac"),   
           "item":"EFG222",  
           "reorder":false,  
   }
```

if you execute below query

```
db.collection_name.update({"json_id":data_json["json_id"], "_dashbd_id_":dashboard_id},{{"$addToSet": {"array_field":keyword}},{ upsert=True})
```

than it will push keyword to array_field if document exist or it will insert new document with following detail as below.

```
     {  
           "_id":ObjectId("5sdvsdv6sdv694ce357ad2a1ac"),
           "json_id":ObjectId("5423200e6694ce357ad2a1ac"),
           "dashboard_id": ObjectId("sddfb6694ce357ad2a1ac")
           "item":"EFG222",  
           "reorder":false,  
           "array_field":
              [                    
              "testingKeyword"
           ]
 }
```